# Faster SQL Performance

Tags: sql-server

I have to insert one record per tables across 30 tables. The data coming from some other System. I have to insert data in the tables for the first time, then if any update happened, then I need to update tables in the SQL Server. I have two options:

a) I can check timestamp for individual table rows and update if the timestamp is greater.

b) Everytime I can stateway delete records and insert data.

Which one will be faster in SQL Server Database? Is there any other option to address the situatation?

Comment: Do you need to worry about the performance 30 single-row inserts? That's nothing. How often does that happen? Why even 30 tables? That's a lot.

Comment: How frequently does this occur? Performance would be a concern only if it's high frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not changing the index fields of the record, the stategy of trying to update first and then insert is usually faster than drop/insert as you don't force the database into updating a bunch of index info.

If using Sql2008+ you should be using the merge command, as it explictly handles the update/insert condition cleanly and clearly

ADDED

I should also add that is you know the usage pattern in rarely update (i.e., 90% insert), you may have a case when drop/insert in faster than update/insert -- depends on lots of details. Regardless, merge is the clear winner if using 2008+

Answer (score 0):

I generally like drop and re-insert. I find it to be cleaner and easier to code. However, if this is happening very frequently and you're worried about concurrency issues, you're probably better off with option 1.

Also, another thing to factor in is how often does the timestamp check fail (where you don't have to insert nor update).  If 99% of data is redundant/outdated data, you're probably better off with option 1 regardless.